# How do I find rows in a pandas dataframe where values have changed?

Tags: python, pandas

I am in a situation where I get data on various items and sometimes some fields for an item changes. I'm looking for an easy way to detect when something has changed. Here's an example. Let's say have like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2],
                   'SUBID': [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'val1': [1, 4, 1, 7, 10, 8],
                   'val2': [2, 5, 2, 8, 11, 9],
                   'val3': [3, 6, 4, 9, 12, 9],
                   'date': ['20200413', '20200413', '20200414', '20200414',
                            '20200415', '20200416']})
```

```
ID  SUBID   val1    val2    val3    date
1   1       1       2       3       20200413
1   2       4       5       6       20200413
1   1       1       2       4       20200414
2   1       7       8       9       20200414
3   1       10      11      12      20200415
2   1       8       9       9       20200416
```

I'd like an operation that gives me something like this:

```
   ID  SUBID   col      date  prev  new
0   1      1  val3  20200414     3    4
1   2      1  val1  20200416     7    8
2   2      1  val2  20200416     8    9
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can do it by first reshaping the dataframe with `set_index`, [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then `groupby` some columns to [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#aggregation) date and the values columns with `first` and/or `last`, then to filter only the one that have changed you can `query`.

```
df_f = (df.set_index(['ID', 'SUBID', 'date'])
          .rename_axis(columns='col').stack()
          .reset_index('date', name='val')
          .groupby(['ID', 'SUBID', 'col'])
          .agg(date=('date','last'), prev=('val','first'), new=('val','last'))
          .query('prev != new').reset_index())

print (df_f)
   ID  SUBID   col      date  prev  new
0   1      1  val3  20200414     3    4
1   2      1  val1  20200416     7    8
2   2      1  val2  20200416     8    9
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach with  [`GroupBy.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) and [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt)

```
new_df = (df.melt(['ID','SUBID','date'], value_name='new')
            .assign(prev=lambda x: x.groupby(['ID','SUBID','variable'])['new']
                                    .shift())
            .loc[lambda x: ~x['new'].eq(x['prev']) & x['prev'].notna()]
            .sort_values(['ID','SUBID']))

print(new_df)
    ID  SUBID      date variable  new  prev
14   1      1  20200414     val3    4   3.0
5    2      1  20200416     val1    8   7.0
11   2      1  20200416     val2    9   8.0
```